# Putting 2 strings together

Tags: c, windows

I have

```
programConfig = fopen("program.conf", "a+");
```

However I need to prepend my system drive letter which is a char* and a couple more directories. I've always been puzzled by this. In PHP for example, you do `string1 . string2`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks!

*Edit: One of the variables might be variable depending on what computer the program is run, namely the system drive letter. "Just so you know" :P*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char pathname[PATH_MAX];
if (snprintf(pathname, sizeof pathname, "%s/%s", dir, file) >= sizeof pathname)
    goto error;
```

Comment: Very nice tip. I'll be using it a lot from now on.

Comment: If you're not familiar with `snprintf`, note that this is the safe and efficient way to build strings. Repeated calls to `strcat` and similar are both heard to avoid buffer overflows or truncation with, and they repeatedly measure the length of the partial string, yielding `O(n^2)` performance.

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention security vulnerabilites from truncating file names.

Answer (score 3):

You must allocate a new char* that is big enough to hold the new string and copy the characters over into it, making sure that it is deallocated at the correct time. You could also use a char[], but the max size is fixed at compile time and you'll need extra checks to prevent buffer overflow.

You will probably find functions such as `strlen`, `calloc`, `free` and `strcat` useful.

Comment: Of course on windows you may also need to be dealing with wide chars in paths, so it's a whole different set of functions.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Unless you use a standard library that provides a UTF-8 view of the filesystem to your program. Cygwin does this and my hope is that Mingw will eventually follow suit. Then you don't have to write nasty Windows-specific filesystem access code.

Comment: By the way, most systems have a reasonable upper bound on pathname lengths. On POSIX, `PATH_MAX`, if present, gives this length. Not sure what it's called on Windows. Using a fixed buffer of that size is a lot easier than allocating, checking for failure, and freeing.

Comment: One nit: you meant to say allocate a new `char []`, not a new `char *`. "Allocate a `char *`" would mean `malloc(sizeof(char *))` which would be rather useless...

Comment: @R - Most windows programmers use neither cygwin nor mingw.

Comment: @R - I actually meant something more like `calloc(n,sizeof(char))`, which returns a `char*` and is not allocating a `char[]`.

Comment: And my nit was one of word usage: `malloc` returns a pointer to what it allocates, so you say it allocates an array of `char`, not a `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a string handling library. Why reinvent the wheel?

http://www.zork.org/safestr/

Or use C++...

Comment: Writing 1-2 lines of idiomatic code is not "reinventing the wheel" and "use language Y instead of language X" is not a good answer to "how do I do [standard task] in language X?"

Comment: What? I've seen people ask such questions and then discover they've ended up writing their own string handling functions that duplicate existing libraries. Sure, my C++ comment was a bit flippant, but suggesting a string handling library? No. Perhaps the OP will go on to use it for a dozen other things - this is unlikely to be the only place of string handling in the code. If its really 1-2 lines then how come the top answer is a description of allocating memory, copying bytes etc etc. Do it safe in one line and I'll vote you up!

Comment: Sorry, I used an extra line for the goto to avoid scrolling. :-)

Comment: And I don't think it's wrong to suggest considering a string library. But I think it's wrong to suggest that by foregoing a fancy string library, you'll necessarily end up "reinventing the wheel". Handling strings in plain C with no fancy library is not as hard as people make it out to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to limit your buffer to `MAX_PATH` anyway (as 99% of Windows applications do), you can simply use the [`PathAppend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shlwapi function.

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
buffer[0]=_T('c') /* the drive letter */
buffer[1]=_T(':');
if(!(PathAppend(buffer, directory) && PathAppend(buffer, _T("program.conf")))
{
    /* handle the error */
}
/* now in buffer you have your string */
```

(here I've declared buffer as `TCHAR` for maximum generality, if you want to use plain chars you can change `TCHAR` to `char` and remove all the `_T` macros; if you instead want to use `wchar_t`s, change `TCHAR` to `wchar_t`, remove the `_T` and stick a `L` after each string/character literal)

If instead you have your full directory path ready in a buffer `MAX_PATH` characters long, you can simply do

```
if(!PathAppend(buffer,_T("program.conf")))
{
    /* handle the error */
}
```

The nice thing is that `PathAppend` handles automagically the necessary backslashes (when they are needed) and returns `FALSE` if the buffer isn't big enough.

If you want to manipulate paths on Windows, you should really have a look at the [Shell Path Handling Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Notice that to use them you must `#include <shlwapi.h>` and link against `shlwapi.lib`.

Answer (score -1):

Use [strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/).

```
char filepath[1024];
char drive[] = "C:\\", dir[] = "dir\\", file[] = "file.txt";

strncpy(filepath, drive, sizeof(filepath)-1);
strncat(filepath, dir, sizeof(filepath)-strlen(filepath)-1);
strncat(filepath, file, sizeof(filepath)-strlen(filepath)-1);
programConfig = fopen(filepath, "a+");
```

Note that in this case since the path is composed of strings known a priori, strcpy/strcat would have sufficed insted of strncpy/strncat, but whenever using user input you should usually use the strncpy/strncat (or even strlcpy/strlcat if available) unless you properly dynamically allocate memory.

Also note that using the strncpy/strncat varieties won't magically protect from all possibly vulnerabilities -- by cutting off the string you may allow the user to access something other than what you checked: ie ("c:\really really really really long file path\file.txt" may be OK when you check it, but the strncpy/cat may truncate it to "c:\real" for example which may not be OK).

Comment: @R.. My bad, wasn't being careful enough. Thanks for pointing it out, I've fixed it above.

Comment: Look at how many times you're uselessly traversing the whole length of the string, and how much more complexity this adds - not to mention the issue that `strncpy` does not null-terminate but *does* uselessly null-pad the tail of the buffer, if there's any space left. Since the buffer is large enough for the constant strings you provided, there's no bug, but there will be a major vuln (in your new version of the code too!) as soon as the user gets to supply the strings. Just *don't use* the `strncpy` function.